# Where to get help for the package options?

Tags: packages, package-options

OS: Windows 7 + SP1
TeX: MiKTeX 2.9
IDE: Kile 2.1

For getting help on usage of package options, I usually Google "foo options latex", where `foo` is the name of the package. I wanted to know whether the documentation is available on the host machine where my LaTeX is installed. I can see all the packages I am using in the MiKTeX package manager. But in the package manager I am not able to locate the help files associated with the packages (if at all they are present on my computer).

Comment: `texdoc` is your friend: `texdoc <packagename>` should open a web browser with links to the search results

Comment: Where should I type "texdoc <packagename>"? Do you think command prompt is alright?

Comment: Yeah, tried it straight in windows command prompt. Took me directly to the relevant website.

Comment: Note that `texdoc` doesn't take you to a website, it links to documentation *on your machine*! it's a great tool :)

Comment: Yeah! I did not notice that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under most operating systems,

```
texdoc <packagename>
```

will open up the TeX documentation (in your default PDF browser) associated with the package. Alternatively, [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/) contains all the packages that form part of both the MiKTeX and TeX Live distributions, from where you can follow the links to their documentation.

Comment: Don't forget http://texdoc.net